# Laravel custom configuration

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a directory called `custom` in Laravel.

I have added that to the `autoloads` directory of `composer.json`

I have made a file in this directory called "`configs.php`"

Now, in this file, I want to append custom configuration to the Laravel's main `config array` so that it survives for all requests ( I mean it is a base config not a run time config ). How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you just create your config in the config directory as that is where are the configs should be. Has nothing to do with the directory custom you have.

You can just create configs.php in the config directory and that is all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a namespace:

```
Config::addNamespace('custom', 'path/to/custom/dir');
```

Get an item from your custom config.php file:

```
Config::get('custom::config.item');
```

More info here: http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-configuration